# How to Export Gridview to Excel, working in Local but not when deployed through IIS

Tags: mysql, asp.net, excel, iis, gridview

My web application connects to MySql database, and users filter the data in Gridview by selecting date range, my problem now is when the users click the Export_button,the Exportfile(Excel) shows but not in users computer but in the Server? i want it to show it with their computers, can you please help me. Thanks appreciate your reply.

Code behind in Export_Button

```
 protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
            int StartCol = 1;
            int StartRow = 1;
            int j = 0, i = 0;

            //Write Headers

            for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow, StartCol + j];
                myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
                }

            StartRow++;

            //Write datagridview content
            for (i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet1.Cells[StartRow + i, StartCol + j];
                        myRange.Value2 = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text == null ? "" : GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exception you getting? I think Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet might not available in your hosting environment

Comment: i'm not getting any exception when i put the Identity of Excel into "The Interactive User", but when i put it in "The Launching User" this error appears "Microsoft Excel cannot open or save any more document because there is not enough available memory or disk space"

Answer (score 0):

after thoroughly searching into net, i finally solved my problem, i hope it may help you in the near future.

I used the Aspose method, it was great and perfect solution! Below is my new code behind my Export_Button hopes it helps!

```
     //Instantiate a new workbook
            Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook();
            //Get the first worksheet in the workbook
            Aspose.Cells.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            //Import data from GridView control to fill the worksheet
            worksheet.Cells.ImportGridView(GridView1, 0, 0, new Aspose.Cells.ImportTableOptions() { IsFieldNameShown = true });
            worksheet.AutoFitColumns();
            //Send result to client in XLS format
            workbook.Save(this.Response, "export.xls", ContentDisposition.Attachment, new Aspose.Cells.XlsSaveOptions());
```